# Is it possible to custom the image in Allure report?

Tags: python, pytest, allure

I am trying to test an app, and when something goes wrong, it will snapshot, and record the click position. When generating the report, I hope that the report can show the click position (like a circle attached to the pitcher). Now the question is:

1. How to record additional information(like click position) when the test is running(use `pytest`)? I found an `allure.dynamic.label` function, is that a solution?
2. How to change the pitcher at report generating?

Comment: It is not work for `allure.dynamic.label` to record the position info, but maybe work with add position info to name at `allure.attach.file`.